# Javascript files in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

So I have an app I'm working on, I've installed a few packages (namely twbs bootstrap, accounts and a few collections ones) and am starting to work on the way it looks. However, I'm trying to include a JS file that doesn't seem to be working.

Is there a good way to include js files, such as some jquery etc? I've noticed both jquery and my js file are being loaded in the head but just don't seem to be working. On my design (standard html page) the file is working fine, so the code isn't wrong.

I'm quite new with Meteor, so is there something I need to do with my routes or the way templates are loaded etc?

Any help would be much appreciated! I've looked everywhere :(

Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to include scripts as you normally would via the `<script>` tag. If I need a specific JS lib, my first step is to search on [Atmosphere](http://atmospherejs.com) to see if someone else has wrapped it into a Meteor package. If not, you can always just take the `.js` file (unminified) and drop it into a folder such as `/client/lib/third-party` and it should work fine.

Without more details such as which script you're trying to get working, or without seeing your code, this is the best help I can offer. Give the above a shot and see how that works out.

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor all files are *"preprocessed"*. By default all JS files are loaded (and executed) on the Client and the Server. This default *locus* is called *common* code. It is shared code between client and server. Common CSS files are only loaded on the client. Then there is `client` and `server` specific code. These `js` files are saved in certain places. client-side code is saved in `/client`, server side in `/server`.

This means that you'll want your code to be inside the `/client` directory. You might call the file `/client/main.js`. All Libraries included via packages (ex. jQuery) are available to these files.

[I'd also strongly recommend reading this before going forward.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)

P.S.: jQuery is in the Meteor-Core and is guaranteed to stay in there so you don't *have* to manually add it. There's no harm to it dough and it might be considered good style.

Comment: Hey Krieg thanks for your reply.

I did just this, I already had all the correct folder structure in place but it's in the client folder and well, doing nothing...

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's an error with the js conflicting with a package or something else in Meteor. I created a separate js file to test it should be working correctly and it is.

I'm still not getting any errors with the one I want to work, it's just not working!